# Trying to install Aeon with XBMC

Tags: xbmc

I am trying to follow this tutorial on installing the aeon add-on to xbmc but I am stumped at the 2.1 part where it instructs me to go to applications->accessories->terminal and clone the repository with the git clone. Can someone walk me through it?

http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=49958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that you don't actually want the repo and just want the skin Aeon on your XBMC

If this is the case then Good News! You are extremely over complicating things!
The way to do this is very simple, open XBMC->Settings->Appearance->Skin then either select a skin that you have or select Get More to download more skins (Aeon).

Comment: Thanks reznoir.  I actually stumbled upon that while messing with it.  I am not sure why I was following the other tutorial.  But I am still confused because I assumed the aeon skin would show box covers and movie info like the youtube videos show.  It still has the same file select screen as the standard XBMC when under the video tab.  I thought maybe I needed one of the scraper add-ons but that doesnt seem to be working for me either.

Comment: Are you able to see the videos that you have? have you added them to the library or are you just looking at the files? You do need a scraper to get the images and information about the films etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all your help.  Linux and it's community never stops amazing me.  One more question.  I enabled the weather option but I can't find anywhere to change it from Celsius to Fahrenheit.  I tried the yahoo and world weather and neither of them have that option and I don't see it under system.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  It seems as soon as I post a question I figure it out.  Thanks again for all your help.  Problems solved.